# Clarification of Isochrony Definition

Tags: terminology, syllable-timing, rhythm

When we speak of isochrony, do we refer to isochrony within a phrase or within a whole language?  E.g. should Mandarin, as a syllable-timed language, have equal duration of syllables within one phrase, or should all syllables of the Mandarin language be equal in duration?  Can the syllables in one phrase in Mandarin be equal in duration, but have a different duration from syllables of another phrase?